# Which CD-based antivirus can scan ICH10 RAID1 array?

Tags: raid, anti-virus

I need to scan my Windows 7 system while booted from CD. However, my system is installed on ICH10 (Intel Matrix Storage) RAID1 array. I tried AVG Rescue CD, however it didn't detect my RAID array.

Question: Which bootable CD antivirus can mount and scan Intel Matrix Storage (ICH10) RAID1 Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAID support had been added to [Kaspersky Rescue Disk 10](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208282145)

Comment: This is an excellent CD-based antivirus, it detected my RAID, showed correct drive letters, has built-in browser for virus information search, etc. Gentoo Linux based.